# Changing the session cookie name

Tags: spark-java

I am using Spark Java with the embedded Jetty to run the application. The application is a small web app with multiple integrations with certain external services depending upon a certain configuration.

The requirement is that the customer should be able to run multiple integrations in the same server in different ports i.e. for eg: application runs on different ports 8080 and 8084 with different integration enabled. The issue is that the session cookie clashes when the user tries to access both applications in the same browser and it creates issues. Is there a way I can change the session variable from JSESSIONID to something else? Or is there a way I can inform Spark to include port too in the cookie domain?

I tried setting the cookie domain using `getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setDomain()` but `getServletContext()` is always returning NULL.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

[this](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/813/commits/92db59208c47c3bddab2384a920d26777635ae6a) pull requested from march of 2017 made it possible to fine tune the embedded jetty like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ...args) throws Exception {
        EmbeddedServers.add(EmbeddedServers.Identifiers.JETTY, (Routes routeMatcher, StaticFilesConfiguration staticFilesConfiguration, boolean hasMultipleHandler) -> {
            MatcherFilter matcherFilter = new MatcherFilter(routeMatcher, staticFilesConfiguration, false, hasMultipleHandler);
            matcherFilter.init(null);

            JettyHandler handler = new JettyHandler(matcherFilter);
            handler.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("XSESSION");

            return new EmbeddedJettyServer((int maxThreads, int minThreads, int threadTimeoutMillis) -> {
                return new Server();
            }, handler);
        });

        get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
            req.session(true);
            return "Hello World";
        });
    }
}
```

now you can verify the results with curl like this:

```
curl -v localhost:4567/hello
```

and the resulting output will give you following `Set-Cookie` header:

```
Set-Cookie: XSESSION=node01j56de4fpp69kl2ye6br6cvno0.node0;Path=/
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution only works for version 2.6 but not on 2.7.

Comment: sorry, i have not looked into this problem in 2.7